# Reading JSON encoded Array form cakePHP view controller

Tags: json, cakephp

Hello I have a JQuery/Ajax function as following:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "/posts/getids", 
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);                                                                  
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('An unexpected error has occurred! Please try later.');
    }
});
```

In my cakePHP script I'm sending an array using the json_encode($array) function.

In firebug I get this result :

```
[{"Post":{"id":1}},{"Post":{"id":2}},{"Post":{"id":4}},{"Post":{"id":3}}]
```

So my question is How can I simply print only the ids like this : 1, 2, 3, 4

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert JSON to JavaScript array.
var dataFromServer = JSON.parse(response);

// Creating an array of id's.
var idArray = [];

// Moving data to "idArray".
for(i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++){
    idArray[i] = dataFromServer[i].Post.id;
}

// Checking the result.
console.log(idArray);

// [1, 2, 3, 4].
```